# on html form submit open modal passing him the data

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a simple form like this:

```
<form id="submit-button">
        <label for="name">Serial number:</label>

        <input type="text" name="form_serialno" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Serial nomber"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="form_idorder" value="<?PHP echo $idorder; ?>">    
        <input type="hidden" name="form_customer" value="<?PHP echo $Customer; ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

I simply want that when I press submit, it shows a bootstrap modal and send to the modal the data of the form from the 3 input.

I already have a list of all items, and with a button near every item I can call the bootstrap modal (using data-fields and call from javascript with "button.data".)
But now I want that with a barcode scanner I can scan the identifier of the item and that the page then populate the modal with the data I've populated in the form, but I don't understand how can I pass the data form the form to the modal.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery events, add a listener to form for "submit".
Add the following code to your js.

```
function handleModal(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get the input data.
  var input1 = $('input[name="form_serialno"]').val();
  var input2 = $('input[name="form_idorder"]').val();
  var input3 = $('input[name="form_customer"]').val();
  //Manipulate the data here.
  // Example:
  //$('#<id-of-modal-element>').text(input1);
  // Show the modal
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  return false;
}
$('#submit-button').on('submit',handleModal);
```